# VBscript runtime error

Tags: vbscript

I have a VBScript that I am working on building. The script itself complets all of the functions within it - it throws an error only after the script ends. It is giving me the following error:
    vbscript runtime error: Object required 'objFSO'

Here is the relavant function:

```
Function ReadFileIntoArray (sFile)
    dim objFSO 'As FileSystemObject
    dim file
    dim volumes()

    Set file = objFSO.OpenTextFile(sFile)  'Error Thrown Here.
    do while not file.AtendOfStream
        redim preserve text(nlines)
        volumes(nlines) = file.Readline
        nlines = nlines + 1
    loop

    file.close
    set file = nothing
    Set objFSO = nothing

    ReadFileIntoArray = volumes
end Function
```

The file is still opened and used properly. I'm a little lost. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

`objFSO` is never assigned a value. When the error occurs, `objFSO`'s value is `Empty`, which is not an object.

You're probably missing

```
   Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
```

Comment: Thanks for the response - I will test it now and let you know the results!

Answer (score 0):

@Nutsy: @Thom Smith has the answer, I just think you might need to explicitly set how you wish to open the file as well though. I've updated your code to include some `constants`:

```
Function ReadFileIntoArray (sFile)
    dim objFSO 'As FileSystemObject
    dim file
    dim volumes()

    Const ForAppending = 8
    Const ForReading   = 1
    Const ForWriting   = 2

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")        
    Set file = objFSO.OpenTextFile(sFile, ForReading)  'Error Thrown Here.
    do while not file.AtendOfStream
        redim preserve text(nlines)
        volumes(nlines) = file.Readline
        nlines = nlines + 1
    loop

    file.close
    set file = nothing
    Set objFSO = nothing

    ReadFileIntoArray = volumes
end Function
```

There may be some other issues in the script as well, I'm unsure what `redim preserve text(nlines)` will do since you never define or use `text` anywhere again and you never define or initialise `nlines` as `0` either.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using somewhat like:

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 

strVar = ReadFileIntoArray(File)
```

it goes into the Function, then you need not to reassign an objFSO just write:

```
Function ReadFileIntoArray (sFile)

dim file
dim volumes()

Set file = objFSO.OpenTextFile(sFile)  'Error Thrown Here.
do while not file.AtendOfStream
    redim preserve text(nlines)
    volumes(nlines) = file.Readline
    nlines = nlines + 1
loop

file.close
set file = nothing
Set objFSO = nothing

ReadFileIntoArray = volumes
end Function
```